# How to set title of button in MenuItem ActionBar

Tags: android, menuitem, classcastexception

I have an application that is connected and disconnected. These two states are handled by a single button. However, that was clear to the user, when you click Connect, the app must change the name of the button to disconnect, and unlike too. I tried to do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int panel, MenuItem item) {

    showToast(item.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    if(item.getTitle().equals("Conectar") && 
            item.getItemId() == (R.id.connectionButton))
    {
        ConnectProcess con = new ConnectProcess(Configuration.this); 
        con.execute();
        item.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.disconnect));
    }
    else if(item.getTitle().equals("Desconectar") &&
            item.getItemId() == (R.id.connectionButton))
    {
        LoadCompany loadCompany = new LoadCompany(Configuration.this);
        loadCompany.execute();
        item.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.connect));
    }

    return true;
}
```

When I run the command, the following exception is being thrown. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
06-09 15:08:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 15:08:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1219): Process: com.sisteplantbrasil.prisma3mobilev2, PID: 1219
06-09 15:08:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1219): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to android.view.MenuItem
06-09 15:08:26.140: E/AndroidRuntime(1219):     at com.sisteplantbrasil.prisma3mobilev2.Configuration.setConnectionButtonText(Configuration.java:105)
```

Comment: Look here, this could help you: 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726602/how-to-refer-menuitem-that-is-defined-in-menu-xml

Comment: You did make a good try at getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me more of your logCat.Normally the line wich create the error is write on it.

But if i understand your question,you can use "seText()".

Here a code example:

```
//
button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
button1.setOnClickListener(yourListener);
private OnClickListener yourListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setText("Your New Txt");
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the actionbar menus in the support actionbar. call the super method `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` `onCreateOptionsMenu` will then be called where you can change the menu.  There is also `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method witch does the same thing on the non support version of the actionbar.

```
public class Whatever extends ActionBarActivity {
boolean action_connect = false;

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int x = item.getItemId();
    switch (x) {
    case R.id.action_connect:
        action_connect = true;
        super.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (action_connect) {
}
```